# Prolog: Access read from parent rule

Tags: prolog

I want a specific rule for reading user input data in SWI-Prolog, something like:

```
process( ... ) :-
    % do_stuff
    read_values( ... ),
    % do_more_stuff with X and Y here.

read_values( ... ) :-
    write('Please enter X: '),        
    read(X),
    write('Please enter Y: '),        
    read(Y).
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you kinda already had the solution:

```
process :-
    % do_stuff
    read_values(A, B),
    % do_more_stuff with X and Y here
    atom_concat(A, B, C),
    writeln(C).

read_values(X, Y) :-
    write('Please enter X: '),        
    read(X),
    write('Please enter Y: '),        
    read(Y).
```

Example run:

```
?- process.
Please enter X: a.
Please enter Y: b.
ab
true.
```

Comment: I'd also made `read_values` non-retractable (or how is that called), but that is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @Lyth: if you mean 'non backtrack able' (or deterministic): read and write are already of that kind

Comment: Thanks, @Mog. Just had to put the pieces together to realize how to do it.